# Why does Chrome show huge empty boxes in web pages?

Tags: google-chrome

How do I fix it? Is there anything I can do to fix it? I tried reinstalling it but it's still the same.

[image]

Comment: Which graphics card?

Answer (score 1):

First off, if you have "Download Accelerator Plus Extension" for Chrome, uninstall it and restart your browser to see if that works.

If you do not or that did not work, go to YouTube and sign-out. Once you've signed out of YouTube, sign back in using your Google credentials.

Both of these methods have worked on more than one occasion, the ladder fixed mine.